# Search/Sorting Algorithms - Model or ViewModel (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm new to the MVVM concept, hence I have a question. I'm wanting to store an array of objects into the Model (arrItems with type arraylist). I'm wanting to implement the Binary Search, but with that I'll need to make sure the arraylist is sorted correctly according to the object's arbitrary field of type Integer.

Should the Binary search and the sorting algorithms go into the Model or the ViewModel. I'm planning on using a Get Method that returns the object, but it seems safer if I include those algorithms in the same file where the arraylist is declared.

We were always taught this way, but other ways are welcome.

Comment: _"with type arraylist"_ - No. You don't want to do that \*waves hand : _"We don't recommend that you use the ArrayList class for new development. Instead, we recommend that you use the generic List<T> class._" - [The DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-7.0#remarks)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ohh okay I see, thank you for the suggestion. So I have a file called DBConfig which essentially just acts as the place where the database loads its tables into the respective 'Arraylists' (in their own separate times). That particular spot uses just one flexible method depending on which Model called it. Is it possible to change the List <T> datatype, depending on which Model calls it (Model as in the MVVM)? Or would I need separate methods for each class used?